# Using nmap's sql-injection script to scan a specific web folder

Tags: debian, nmap

I'm fairly new to linux and nmap. I'm using debian squeeze. I tried installing an SQL-injection script for nmap. I was able to successfully run a test scan agains my web server running Windows. However, I can't seem to tell the script to run an SQL-injection test on a certain directory. I tried the following commands, but none of them are scanning the directory I want to scan. I'm trying to scan `http://some.url/TESTNMAP`:

```
nmap --script=sql-injection 10.10.10.10 --script-args sql-injection.start=TESTNMAP/
nmap --script=sql-injection 10.10.10.10 --script-args start=TESTNMAP/
```

For some reason, the `--script-help` option is just not available, so I can't run:

```
nmap --script-help sql-injection
```

Comment: Are you missing a leading `/`? Example: `sql-injection.start=/TESTNMAP/`

Comment: just tried that. no luck ask well. It keep on showing stuff at the root level. I even tried --script-args='sql-injection.start=/nmaptest/'

Comment: Assuming it is this script: http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/sql-injection.html, the documentation seems to indicate that is just spiders a site, so it most likely ignores the provided path.